# Why does my array value in my map not get updated?

Tags: ruby

If I have:

```
map = Hash.new { [] }
```

It shows that map['a'] (or any other arbitrary key) is initialized to [], as I expected. But when I try to update it with:

```
map['a'] << 15
```

Then my map doesn't change at all. Is it supposed to? Am I doing something incorrectly? Is this just not supported when the actual key does not exist, even though it's supposed to have a default value?

Comment: bad idea to call your hash `map`.

Comment: Yeah, that seriously tripped me up :P

Answer (score 1):

That isn't how you use a block to initialize a hash. The block receives the new hash, and the key being accessed, and leaves it up yo you to define the associated value.

You need the following:

```
map = Hash.new { |hash,key| hash[key] = [] }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a block to intiialize the hash `{|h,k| h[k] = [] }`

Or you can do `map['a'] = 15` this will allow map to be a hash with `a` pointing to `15`